# Auto hex bin dumps modifying program?

Tags: python, binary, hex, bin

I've been using a simple hex editor to manually modify hex `.bin` dumps for past 3 years.
I work with `.bin` hex files which need overwriting of bytes or values (not sure about correct term) in certain areas of the dump.

Example:

`dumps "HCA"` always need bytes from position 00AF to position 10A4 overwritten with bytes "0000".

`dumps "TLC"` always need bytes from position 20AA to position 40AF overwritten with bytes "0000".

Instead of me constantly doing this manually in the hex editor I thought of creating a python hex editor program that does is automatically somehow like this:

1. Open python program.
2. Select hex overwriting template ( according to dump type that will need to be modified.)
3. Browse and Select dump file thru window.
4. python creates a backup copy of dump and loads dump into memory / buffer.
5. Dump gets modified according to the selected dump type in step 2.
6. window pops up asking where to save the modified dump
7. user selects the  directory and new name for the modified dump and clicks "save"
8. modified dump gets saved in chosen directory under the newly selected name

Comment: What is your question? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Questions are:  is this possible to make in python to be implemented into a webpage ? What's the easiest way to do this ? To have macros for modifying dumps in one python program or create separate one for each dump type ? And biggest question how can write a command to be able to chose which dump file to load into memory

Comment: Where are these `.bin` files? If they're not on the webpage's server, it's unlikely you would be able to modify them. It's certainly possible to modify the files, but the Python script would have to be run on the computer where they reside. Python scripts can be run from the command line and can have either a terminal console-based user-interface or a graphical one. To implement the latter, you would need to use something like the `tkinter` module. In both cases you could present the user with a list of dump files to process, but it would depend on which user-interface is being used.

Comment: bin files will be provided by the users that need them modified. pretty much I want to create a webpage, but first have to create the programm that will be implemented in that webpage, like this webpage: http://carprogonline.com/, where users upload a file according to the part number, the online program modifies it and user downloads it. to get an idea how that online program work, type in "77960TR0A212M1" into "enter part number" field, than the part number with description will pop up, click on that, and it will bring up the next screen to upload a bin file for modifying

Comment: Regardless, the `.bin` files to be modified don't reside on the server (do they?).

Comment: no, users upload them for modifying

Comment: pretty much I want to create a webpage with hex .bin modifying program , like these webpages: https://www.weboctopus.nl/airbag-srs-repair-clear-clean-reset-crash.php , 
http://carprogonline.com/airbag ,        http://www.codecard.eu/MAC/index.php?code=honda ,           https://www.tachosoftonline.com/ , https://www.airbagreset.sk/en/227-civic ,

Comment: In that case I suggest you ask a new question and limit its scope to how to modify a `.hex` file according to some "hex overwriting template". You should also show your own attempt at doing this.